# What is the proper way to call multiple methods from a single event?

Tags: c#, events, methods, picturebox, multicastdelegate

I'm calling multiple color correction methods from a pictureBox click event.  The problem is, sometimes a method will be skipped.  Sometimes a method will run twice.  So I may not be using the best possible way to call my methods. Code follows:

EDIT: I received a comment stating that the question is unclear. It seems  clear to me. But in case I'm wrong, let me clarify: *I am getting errors with my current way of calling multiple methods.  What is the proper way to do so?*

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox0.Image = pictureBox1.Image;                  

    foreach (PictureBox item in Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
    {
        item.Image = pictureBox0.Image;
        item.Refresh(); 
    }

    runColorMethods();  
}      

private void runColorMethods()
{
    red();
    orange();
    yellow();
    green();
    blue();
    magenta(); 
}
```

It would take too much space to show all six methods, one will suffice.

```
private void red()
{
    // declare initial variables 
    int xRed = 32;

    lock (lockObject)
    {
        // Get bitmap from picturebox
        Bitmap bmp1 = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;

        // search through each pixel via x, y coordinates, examine and make changes. 
        // Dont let values exceed 255 or fall under 0.  
        for (int y = 0; y < bmp1.Height; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < bmp1.Width; x++)
            {
                Color c = bmp1.GetPixel(x, y);
                int myRed = c.R, myGreen = c.G, myBlue = c.B;
                myRed += xRed;
                if (myRed > 255)
                    myRed = 255;
                bmp1.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(255, myRed, myGreen, myBlue));
             }

        // assign the new bitmap to the picturebox
        pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)bmp1;
    }
```

}

I've heard of multicast delegates being used to call multiple methods, but I do not know how to use them correctly, or if they are even the best way to go.   Recommendations?

Comment: "The problem is, sometimes a method will be skipped." -- Why do you think so?

Comment: It is unclear what your question is. What you're doing is a very good way to call multiple methods. What exactly is the question here? If you want to use multicast methods you would just hook up multiple methods to the event, which can't be done using the property inspector of the form/control, you need to do that in code.

Comment: And when you say skipped / run twice, is that a problem you want help solving, or is that logic you've not shown that does this that just explains the complexity of "multiple methods"? As I said, your question is unclear.

Comment: @ Lews Therin - I have no clue, that's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: @   Lasse V. Karlsen - Yes, skipped / run twice is a problem I'd appreciate help solving.

Comment: Write to a log / trace in the event handler and in your methods. See in what sequence they are called to get a better picture.

Comment: You say, that you are getting errors. Please post further informations about this errors here (for example Exception details).

Comment: @  DrKoch That sounds helpful.  I'm new to C#, and don't know how to go about doing that.  How do I write to a log / trace in the event handler and methods? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Marvin I have resolved all of the exception errors. The problem I'm having here is that sometimes methods are skipped, sometimes they are run twice. Thank you